# Import of CSV file data to PostgreSQL table automation

Tags: postgresql, psql

Below import command works fine if the nrgcore.bookmarks table is empty, please let me know how to include 'truncate table ngrcore.bookmarks' in the below command so that it first truncate the table and then import the data successfully.

```
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb -c "COPY nrgcore.bookmarks(login, application, description, centerx, centery, scale, bookmarkid, path) FROM 'D:\Bookmarks_Table\Bookmarks.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER"
```

Any help/suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Add the `TRUNCATE` statement before `COPY` in the `-c` option, separated by a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing inline query, You can create one sql file that contains below :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE nrgcore.bookmarks;

COPY nrgcore.bookmarks(login, application, description, centerx, centery, scale, bookmarkid, path) FROM 'D:\Bookmarks_Table\Bookmarks.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

And pass it in your command line argument:

```
psql -U nrgadmin -d enwdb -f import.sql
```

Comment: Glad i could help. But be careful with truncate.

Comment: Yup no problem. I'm aware of it. Thanks.